# safe-global/auth-kit CORS policy issues on localhost

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I'm trying to integrate safe-global/auth-kit and upon initialization of SafeAuthPack I'm getting CORS issues on localhost. Is there any workaround for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey Chufta, thanks for your question! We were able to replicate the bug and confirm we had the same issue. We are currently looking into what could be causing the problem. Please hang tight!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `txServiceUrl: "https://safe-transaction-polygon.safe.global"` is incorrect, URL should be `https://safe-transaction-polygon.safe.global/api`.

Since the SDK will automatically map the correct URL to the chain you are using, you can actually remove this parameter entirely and simply do `new SafeAuthPack()`.

Hope it helps! Best, Louis